# How can I make a protocol method in swift optional?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

How can I make a protocol method in swift optional? Now all the methods in a protocol is seems to be required. Is there any other work arounds?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use optional methods, mark your protocol with `@objc`

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {

    optional func someMethod();

}
```

As stated in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID284).

Answer (score 6):

While you can use `@objc` in Swift 2 you can add a default implementation and you don't have to provide the method yourself:

```
protocol Creatable {
    func create()
}

extension Creatable {
    // by default a method that does nothing
    func create() {}
}

struct Creator: Creatable {}

// you get the method by default
Creator().create()
```

However in Swift 1.x you could add a variable which holds an optional closure

```
protocol Creatable {
    var create: (()->())? { get }
}

struct Creator: Creatable {
    // no implementation
    var create: (()->())? = nil

    var create: (()->())? = { ... }

    // "let" behavior like normal functions with a computed property
    var create: (()->())? {
        return { ... }
    } 
}

// you have to use optional chaining now
Creator().create?()
```